# Drupal 6 module for adding CCK-like fields to comments?

Tags: drupal, cck, drupal-comments

I'm needing to allow users of a site to add structured comments to nodes. Are there any stable modules out there for Drupal 6 that will enable me to do this? I'm thinking along the lines of being able to add CCK-like fields to the comment type. In an ideal situation the administrator would be able to alter/change the questions being asked on a node-by-node basis, but not necessary. We're after a simple solution if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the [Node comments module](http://drupal.org/project/nodecomment). It allows you to use nodes as comments, which makes it possible to use CCK fields in them.

The currently maintained 2.0 version is still in beta, though.

Comment: Apart from the fact that this is in beta it looks very promising thanks. I had originally thought that comments were going to work a little like this anyway with Drupal's usual approach of everything having a node reference.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to wait for Drupal-7 with *fields in core* before something like that is available. Currently there is no module/patch etc. that allows you to do something like that.

If you really want to, you could create a module from scratch, but that would be quite a challenge in itself.